# Allowing html5 data attributes in tinymce editor

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, tinymce-4

How to allow html5 data attributes in tinymce editor? Tinymce removes the custom attributes specified to a tag. How can I prevent tinymce from removing it?

Comment: Did the answer below solve your issue?  If so you should select it as correct so others don't invest time trying to answer the question and if others find your question via search they will know the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can allow these in TinyMCE by adding the `extended_valid_elements` option to your TinyMCE configuration.  For example you could do this:

```
extended_valid_elements: "*[*]"
```

...which should allow any tag or attribute or you can be more specific about what you want to add:

```
extended_valid_elements: "+@[data-options]"
```

This should specifically add support for `data-xxx` attributes on any tag but would otherwise not change what TinyMCE allows.

***Note:*** I note you have the WordPress tag on this question.  It is possible that while TinyMCE would allow a tag or attribute that WordPress would remove it on save ... if you see the attribute in the "code" view but not after its saved that is likely a WordPress issue.